# Dynamic cast at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, types, casting

Is there a way to dynamically cast at runtime like the following pseudo code:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    {
        if (row[col] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            Type type = col.DataType;

            type cellContent = (type)row[col]; //Pseudo-Code
        }
    }
}
```

I´ve been searching the web and not found anything. There´s `object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);`, but then I´m still stuck with an object and can´t use specific type methods with it. Also I need a cast of an existing object and not a new instance. I need to remove all EventHandlers from CellContent as in certain cases they cause a memory leak, example: Object type is IList[SerialNumberGridViewModel] and SerialNumberGridViewModel implements PropertyChanged-Handler which is causing a memory leak. Any idea? Is there a way to solve this issue?

I´ve already solved it in the above specific case, but a general method would be a lot better, as the program I´m working with is big and has a lot of memory leaks to be removed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you give an example with sample data?

Comment: No, because that doesn't make any sense. How would you use `cellContent` since you still don't know what the type is. If you know the members you want to access then the best solution is to create a type (e.g. an interface or base class) containing those members and then cast to that type. If you can't do that, use `dynamic` or reflection.

Comment: Your pseudo-code does nothing currently. It's unclear what you are asking. And memory leakage is totally different story, either remove it or ask another question.

Comment: There is some misunderstanding. Could you give an example of what you want to do with "cellContent" variable next if you don't know it's type? may be reflection is what are you looking for?

Comment: @Sinatr: If I´ve cast the cellContent to the object it actually is, I can remove its events. The line marked as pseudo code is just to demonstrate what I´m actually trying to do - which it does. So why is it unclear?

Comment: Have a look at the answer Zohar Peled gave - thats what I wanted to know. Also Lee understood the question. So, why downvote that fast? My post was 3 minutes ago and I have not had any time to clarify. Not very fair in my opinion.

Comment: I haven't downvoted ... yet ;). Still it's unclear. If this code is inside [generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) method, then you can surely do `(T)(object)` cast. So I insist on clarification, how will you use `cellContent`? To call its members? Then generics won't do.

Comment: It is not within a generic method, so I can´t. As I stated as an example, the object type SerialNumberGridViewModel implements a PropertyChanged-Event that needs to be removed. If I don´t cast, I can´t remove the event - or am I getting something wrong? The Event is causing a hard-reference and the parent control is not released for GC because of that. In that specific case I know that the object is a SerialNumberGridViewModel, but I´d like a general Method that casts the cellContent to what it is at runtime - understand now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't cast to any type that is unknown at compile time. However, c# does have a special keyword for declaring variables of a type that is unknown - it's [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx).
You can think of it like a form of [late binding](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/babu_2082/early-binding-vs-late-binding/) - The actual type of the variable is determind at run time only.
When you declare a dynamic variable, c# compiler actually creates a variable of type object, but does not perform any type checking.

> The dynamic type enables the operations in which it occurs to bypass compile-time type checking. Instead, these operations are resolved at run time.
>   ...
>   Type dynamic behaves like type object in most circumstances. However, operations that contain expressions of type dynamic are not resolved or type checked by the compiler. The compiler packages together information about the operation, and that information is later used to evaluate the operation at run time. As part of the process, variables of type dynamic are compiled into variables of type object. Therefore, type dynamic exists only at compile time, not at run time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It´s the info I needed.

Comment: I've been a member here for over 3 years. From what I've seen, most good clear questions gets good, clear answers. Sometimes it's just a matter of how you write the question. However, I don't think this question deserves downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'll give it a try. The part about reflection is a bit confusing, but what I think you are looking for is the `Dispose` pattern.

Check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737.aspx

All the classes which would need cleanup code e.g. `SerialNumberGridViewModel` would implement `IDisposable`. From outside you would cast to `IDisposable` and just call `Dispose()`. Every object decides for itself what has to be done now e.g. remove Eventhandlers, etc. etc.

regards